# Why do I need another pair of curly braces?

Tags: math-mode

I have an error in this line of LaTeX.

```
\frac{ {{2}\choose{2}} {{1}\choose{1}} } { {1}\choose{1} }
```

The error notes

```
Ambiguous; you need another { and }.
```

I matched up the curly braces, and I don't think I need one though. What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\choose` macro needs to know where the top and the bottom part starts and ends:

```
\frac{ {2\choose 2} {1\choose 1}}{{1 \choose 1}}
```

But, as far as I know, `\choose` is a plainTeX macro, you better use `\binom` (it is in the same family like `\frac` *but needs the `amsmath` package*):

```
\frac{\binom{2}{2} \binom{1}{1}}{\binom{1}{1}}
```

[image]

You have also `\tbinom` and `\dbinom` for textstyle and displaystyle respectively.

#### Explanation

Consider the following example:

```
{1 + 23 \choose 4a - 7} \neq 1 + {23 \choose 4}a - 7
```

It does render as
[image]

A additional `{23}` and `{4}` just groups those parts with no relation to the `\choose` macro. (Kind of like `\bfseries` does in text mode.)

Comment: Thanks! $\binom$ works great. I still don't see why $\choose$ is erring though. Why does your form tell $\choose$ where the top and bottom ends, and my form does not?

Comment: @DavidFaux `\choose` uses the "primitive" TeX syntax for fractions, where the (almost) equivalent of `\frac{1}{2}` is `{1\over 2}` (the braces can be omitted if the formula has only the fraction). Everything before `\over` (or `\choose`) is the numerator, everything after is the denominator and the braces block the scanning. It's a syntax borrowed from nroff and one of the bad choices Knuth did for TeX.

Comment: Ah, so the braces are causing the error for choose. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidFaux In addition to egreg's comment I added an example that, hopefully, makes it clear. Just for fun, loose one pair of `{}` and compile.

Comment: @egreg: "bad choices Knuth did for TeX.": that's an opinion, but you make it sound like a fact.

Comment: @morbusg Well, it's an opinion that I share with other TeXperts. `:)`

Comment: it's not been stated explicitly so far: when `\choose` is evaluated, the delimiting braces are stripped off.  that removes the braces that `\frac` needs to delimit its arguments. (and yes, this is, sadly, bad design; i've not heard knuth say so, but i think that he'd now agree, as he *has* said regarding the choice of toggled `$` signs as opposed to clear begin/end markers.)

Answer (score 5):

To add to Qrrbrbirlbel's practical answer, I'd like to explain why exactly TeX says that your expression

```
\frac{ {{2}\choose{2}} {{1}\choose{1}} } { {1}\choose{1} }
```

is ambiguous although it doesn't *look* ambiguous. For simplicity let's look at the simpler expression `\frac{1}{ {1}\choose{1} }`. By LaTeX's definition of `\frac`, this expands to

```
{\begingroup 1 \endgroup \over {1}\choose{1} }
```

And here you already see the trouble: TeX has no way to know what is meant,

1. `\begingroup 1 \endgroup` over `{1}\choose{1}`  or
2. `\begingroup 1 \endgroup \over {1}` choose `{1}` .

The braces and `\begin/endgroup` are not relevant here, so essentially the question is:
`1` over `1 \choose 1`, or `1 \over 1` choose `1`?